# Sub-process returned error code (1), low boot memory

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, error-handling, pop-os

System specs: `OS: Pop!_OS 20.04`

It appears that my boot partition is running low on memory, and frankly, not entirely sure what or how that happened. I have some suspicions, but I feel like I'm perpetually a beginner when it comes to fixing kernel related issues. Here is what I'm getting:

`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

the error code (1) indicates to me that some type of error is taking place in the kernel space. What I'm trying to do is trace the issue and locate where the dependency is failing, but unsure where to start. Some other interesting messages I'm not used to seeing:

`cryptsetup: WARNING: Resume target cryptswap uses a key file`

`W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu`

The W: Possible missing firmware... line has different outputs, mostly referring to firmeware associated with my amdgpu directory.

Appreciate any and all help. Worse case scenario is I reinstall and start over. Oh no, I get to play with my computer some more ;)

Be well everyone, Tito

Comment: How much free "boot" or more likely root partition memory do you have. What steps have you taken to free up space?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I vimmed in to /usr/bin/dpkg, which was interesting. Took a look per your comment and have 84% of boot memory used. Next steps are to look at how to make room. Never done it before and should be fun. If you have any suggestions and helpful things to read, it'd be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: You should find that /usr/bin/dpkg is in the same partition as `/`. You are doing a software update/upgrade and it looks like you have an encrypted partition? Perhaps you have more kernel versions installed than needed? [two or three kernel versions is sufficient]. Try running the `lsblk -f` command and posting the output. Do you have your original USB stick from which you installed the system? Why did you choose to encrypt your data?

Comment: That is weird and see that when I run lsblk program.

Comment: I see that when you run lsblk program. I have the original USB from the system install. It gave me an option to encrypt when I installed Pop!_os. Bad idea? This is all learning for me. I'm looking at the name of the mounted ssd, and it's partitioned in to 3 parts: 1p1, 1p2, 1p3. If I have to reinstall the system - no big. I'm more curious about how / why this happened. The one that is sticking out to me is 1p3 with an FSTYPE called swap. The reason it sticks out is there is no FSAVAILABLE or FUSE% space listed, and a MOUNTPOINT labeled [SWAP]. Intuition tells me that's weird.

Comment: You have 3 partitions. Probably ─ nvme0n1p1, nvme0n1p2, nvme0n1p3. p1 will be small and is needed for booting; p2 is system programs and your data; p3 is swap. Do **not** encrypt your system, unless you need to - it makes various recovery options much harder. If you have control, during the install, of partition sizes then you need to adjust the defaults - I don't know anything about your system so its not possible to recommend relative sizes. A search of "linux partition size recommendation" will produce a lot of suggestions, some good, some bad.

Comment: Awesome and helpful. I'll back up the files to my external and reinstall the system with your notes in mind. Also, reading more about partitioning and sizes pertinent to my system. This was tremendously helpful and appreciate your help navigating through it. Learned a lot, and also much more to learn :)